# I can no longer access the BIOS (Computer Freezes)

Tags: bios, fedora, grub, uefi, firmware

I have a new Lenovo T440 with Windows 8.1, I have installed Fedora 22 to have dual boot, I started playing around with grub2-customization and some of the BIOS settings (secure boot and legacy vs UEFI), but now I can no longer access the bios settings, only get a short message in the top left of the screen saying `To interrupt normal startup, press enter`. But when I press enter nothing happens and the laptop seems to be freezed!

It is almost the same problem this guy faced: http://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/34fay2/help_brand_new_t450s_cannot_access_bios/ But the problem I cannot access my Windows OS (for enabling secure boot), I do only have access to Fedora OS.

I tried to unplug the hard disk and plug it again as some guy suggested but that does not solve the problem!

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you pressing the correct set of keys while the computer is booting? Read the manual. Unplugging won't help. You will have to attempt to get into the bios before the computer starts booting the OS.

Comment: Yes, which is Enter key, it was working fine but suddenly after I re-enabled the secure boot I couldn't access the bios settings again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by removing `grub2` package from Fedora, after restart the laptop could only find Windows bootloader and I could access Windows 8.1 OS.. But lost my access to Fedora (this can be solved by updating Fedora from the live CD later).

After logging to Windows 8.1 OS, I fixed the BIOS by doing the following:
- Go to `Advanced Startup Options`
- Chose `Advanced Startup` (requires reboot)
- Chose `Troubleshoot` -> `Advanced Options` -> `UEFI Firmware Settings` -> Follow the instructions

My BIOS is fixed now and can easily access it.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas occur to me:

- **Remove the hard disk** -- If you remove all bootable media from the computer, including your hard disk, it will probably drop back to the firmware setup utility when you start it up. If your laptop makes it hard do remove the hard disk, this might not be a good option; but if you've got easy access to the hard disk, this solution should work well. You might or might not retain access to the firmware after you re-install your disk, though.
- **Firmware variable cleanout** -- I've heard of this sort of problem occurring when a computer's EFI variable storage (used to hold boot loader and other information) collects enough "stray" entries. You might therefore try using `efibootmgr` and/or the `/sys/firmware/efi` directory tree to clean out unused boot entries and other EFI variables. Sometimes Fedora's tools end up creating ridiculous numbers of duplicate boot loader entries, so if `efibootmgr` shows these, they should definitely be trimmed back to just one. Don't delete entries willy-nilly, though; delete only duplicate entries or things you know you aren't using.
- **Complete firmware reset** -- Most machines provide an option to completely reset the firmware. The details depend on your particular machine, though, so I can't provide step-by-step instructions for you. Also, if this reset includes flushing the old boot loader entries, you might find that Fedora will stop booting, at least until you use an emergency disk and `efibootmgr` to restore a suitable entry.
- **Use [gummiboot](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gummiboot) or my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)** -- These boot managers both provide options to boot into the firmware setup utility. If you install rEFInd to your hard disk via the RPM or its `install.sh` script, it should work with Secure Boot (although you'll need to enter the rEFInd key using MokManager, which should launch the first time you boot after installing rEFInd). Gummiboot will be trickier to get working with Secure Boot active. There's a rEFInd USB image, but it doesn't support Secure Boot -- you'd need to add Shim and MokManager to get it to work. If you do that, rEFInd should work from a USB key without installing it to your hard disk. Both boot managers provide menu options to reboot into the firmware setup utility. I don't recall the precise description used by gummiboot, but in rEFInd, the option is a second-row icon that looks like a computer chip. Your description of the system hanging when you try to enter the firmware setup utility in the usual way makes me think that the same might happen if you tried to use rEFInd or gummiboot. Also, not all computers support the feature that gummiboot and rEFInd use to reboot into the firmware setup utility, so the relevant option may be absent from their menus.
- **Use GRUB** -- Some versions of GRUB offer an option to reboot into the firmware setup utility, similar to that provided by gummiboot and rEFInd. It's often not enabled, though. Unfortunately, I don't know precisely how to enable this feature, or even if it's provided by Fedora's version of GRUB. You could do further research to figure out these details, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, unfortunately it was a bit late, I had to sacrifice my fedora by removing grub2-etf package, so I was only able to access my windows 8.1 and then I updated my bios from there, and the bios is fine.